# PHP MVC: load admin settings

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm building an MVC application which has several configuration settings such as thumbnail size etc etc), set by the administrator, stored in the database.

What's the proper way to bring these settings into play? In other words, which part of the MVC should take care of this?

Answer (score 2):

You should process all this data in the Views. Ideally, you would have separate views depending on what you wish to do with the data. Certain views, for example, modifying the data might be restricted to Admins only, etc...

Comment: Are you sure? An avatar is not properly a view property, but a property of the user, like password of age. The View, instead, decide if show-it or not and how.

Comment: There is no one way of doing it. You can write it wherever it makes most sense to you. But ideally such things are processed in the views.

Comment: Due to the MVC design pattern, the View is responsible only on presentation of data coming from the data-layer (Model part). The controller is responsible on parsing http request with the help of framework core components. So having the data being retrieved from DB and parsed inside the View looks mostly like an anti-pattern.

Comment: I think the framework is important in this consideration. For example, in Django, you would do such things in the view only.

Answer (score 0):

You must configuration settings on your Controller.
Read this article
[mvc](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the answer depends on the way you want your configuration settings to be set by administrator.

For instance, if you want to have a separate screen with user controls to assign values to settings accessible to administrator, then you'll have to use all three M-V-C parts.

V will be for html template code of screen with user controls.

M will be an entity class like ConfigurationSetting for ORM-based mapping to the database.

C will orchestrate V and M. First it will connect them with HTTP request coming parsed from the framework being used, then pass the processed template to the framework to generate http response.

The other way is to assign and update settings directly via database. As a tool an administrator could use the db-management tool or DB migrations tool built into your favorite framework. In any case your MVC app will read assigned data using M component and most likely will not be able to modify those settings.